# Como usa api rest con php

Tags: php

Soy nuevo en el tema de usar api rest de redmine y necesito dado un proyecto que se muestren los servicios que hay en ese proyecto, para poder luego operar sobre dichos servicios, el caso es que por mas que intento sacar info siempre me sale o Syntax error, o no me sale nada en mi navegador, y pienso que no lo estoy usando bien o correctamente, aquí tengo mi código de ejemplo:

```
require_once 'php-redmine-api-master/lib/autoload.php';

// Instantiate a redmine client
// --> with ApiKey
$client = new Redmine\Client('http://url.es', 'api_key'); 

print_r($client);


// Trackers
$trackers = $client->tracker->all();
//var_dump($trackers);


$project_id = 119;
$issues = $project_id->issue->all(['project_id' => $project_id]);



print_r($issues);
```

Me podéis decir como listar aunque sea la lista de projects  cuando accedo desde mi **localhost** a la web que necesito acceder ? Estoy bastante pez, gracias.

PD: el print r de client si me saca información y entiendo que sale bien.

Comment: ¿En que versión de `PHP` lo estas corriendo? Como mínimo necesitas usar `PHP5.6` porque estas usando la sintaxis de `['key'=> value]` para crear un arreglo.

Comment: tengo la 7.2.10